# changing of buttons using php

Tags: php, button, action, html

I have a webpage that shows a login panel, and a button which enables the user to register themselves to the site.

Once they have registered, it takes them into the site, but the button is still showing as register, I want it to change to My account, which enables the user to edit their profile, and another button to let them logout. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
 if ($_SESSION['client_id']){
 echo'<a class="button-top" href="index.php?action=member_edit">My Account</a>'
 echo'<a class="button-top" href="index.php?action=logout_ok">Logout</a>'
}else{
 echo'<a class="button-top" href="index.php?action=member_add">Register</a>'

 }

 ?>
```

But it is completely and totally wrong.

Comment: change the text value of the button. If it's just a bunch of literal text now saying "Register", you need to replace it with PHP code so it says "Register" under one condition and "My Account" under another. (I realize that advice sounds like "if you want to do X, just do X". For more specific help, you might want to post some code. It's important to understand though that you don't change a static page using php, you make it dynamic in the first place and then decide what you're going to display)

Comment: Can you tell us how the login form is send to server? Cuz its ajax you need to change the buttons in response. Ifs normal redirect you need to check in your view if the user is logged in and display different html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if statement!

```
if (check_if_user_is_logged()) {
# Run Your Two Buttons For Being Logged In
}else{
# Button To Login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
when not logged in

$btn1 = "Register";

$btn2 = "Login";

after login 

$btn1 = "My Account";
$btn2 = "Log Out";

<input type='button' name='btnRegistration' value="<?php echo $btn1?>" />

<input type='button' name='btnLogin' value="<?php echo $btn2?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

At first store the session value of the user who login. Then in the other page, check whether the session value is there or not. If session value is there then change the signup and login button into signout and welcome message.

So When you are creating the **login.php** page, Pass theseesion like,

```
$query="Select * From Logn_tbl Where username='".$_REQUEST['username']."'And    password='".$_REQUEST['password']."'";

if(mysql_num_rows($check_user_result)>0)

{

 $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];

 header('Location:index.php');

 }
```

Now in **Index.php** page chaeck for **$_SESSION['user_id']**. And write code like,

```
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){ ?>
                     <div>
                        WellCome&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <span>
                          <?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>
                        </span>
                         <div>
                        <a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a>
                     </div>
                     </div>

              <?php  }
                else { ?>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="login.php">Sign In</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="sign_up.php">Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Now After This all, **Logout.php** will be as

```
        <?php
         session_start();
          if(session_destroy()){
      header("Location:login.php");
        }
       ?>
```